# mySql-java simple search console application

Tags: java, mysql, search

I'm trying to do a search program: front end - java and back end - mysql.

I've tried a little bit, here's the code:

```
public static void searchRecord() throws SQLException{

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int empnum;

    System.out.print("Enter employee number: ");
    empnum = in.nextInt();

    String search = "SELECT fname FROM employees WHERE emp_num='"+ empnum + "'";
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(search);

    String empnum_rs = null;    

    while(resultSet.next()){
        empnum_rs = resultSet.getString(empnum);



    }

     System.out.print(empnum_rs);   
}
```

The problem I got here is that when I would type the emp_num eclipse throws these lines:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 2 > 1. 
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkColumnBounds(ResultSetImpl.java:830)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5773)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5692)
    at Test.searchRecord(Test.java:55)
    at Test.main(Test.java:37)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getXXX...` functions take column numbers starting from 1 to n where n is the max number of columns selected in the query. Your query has only one column in selection. And `empnum` might not be equal to 1 and hence an error is thrown.

Change:

```
empnum_rs = resultSet.getString(empnum);
```

to:

```
empnum_rs = resultSet.getString( 1 );
```

Comment: Oh thanks mate! I should have put the column for my emp_num.. thanks again

Comment: You can use either coumn number or column name in the `get...` method.

Comment: but when I added the lname column, it only displayed the fname. How can I concatenate the lastname?

Comment: You can modify select query with require fields concatenated. `select concat(fname, ' ', lname) as user_name from my_table where empnum=?`. It is also advised to use `PreparedStatement` over `Statement`.

Comment: Oh I see sorry such a dumb question, I managed to do it :    String empnum_rs = null; 
  String emplname_rs = null;
   
  while(resultSet.next()){
  empnum_rs = resultSet.getString(1);
  emplname_rs = resultSet.getString(2);
   
  }

  System.out.print(empnum_rs + " " + emplname_rs);
 }